# what are the pros and cons of using specialised GPGPU programs as opposed to compute shaders in graphics API?

Tags: graphics, gpgpu, compute-shader

What are the pros and cons of using specialised GPGPU like CUDA and OpenCL as opposed to Compute Shaders?

Answer (score 0):

CUDA and OpenCL have tons more features and are easier to use. However if you already use OpenGL then it's easier to use Compute Shaders.